# How do I get the value of a <pre> tag with no ID?

Tags: php, html, pre

I have the following code set up from an example:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://somedomain/something';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( '<div id="somediv">' , $content );
$second_step = explode("</div>" , $first_step[1] );

echo $second_step[0];

?>
```

The problem here is that the website from which I'm trying to fetch the value of the pre tag has no ID:

```
<pre>some content</pre>
```

I've also tried this but no success so far:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://somedomain/something';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( '<script>document.getElementsByTagName("pre")' , $content );
$second_step = explode("</script>" , $first_step[1] );

echo $second_step[0];

?>
```

Basically, I'm trying to fetch a value from a domain which is wrapped by a `pre` tag with no additional identifiers. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Why aren't you using a [DOM parser](http://php.net/dom)?

Comment: You mean like this:

<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = 'http://somedomain/something';
foreach ($url->getElementsByTagName("pre"){
echo $pre;
}


?>

Comment: jquery, if its the only pre: $('pre').text(); PHP you can use regex: /<pre>(.*)?</pre>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP ships with a pretty decent document parser:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://somedomain/something');

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('pre') as $node) {
    // do stuff with $node
    echo $node->nodeValue, "\n";
}
```

See also: [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument)

Comment: Thanks! But could you direct what am I doing wrong here?

<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('https://blockchain.info/q/addressbalance/1i7cZdoE9NcHSdAL5eGjmTJbBVqeQDwgw');

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('pre') as $node) {
    // do stuff with $node
    echo $node->nodeValue, "\n";
 }




?>

Comment: @user3079309 Nothing wrong, except that the document you have specified doesn't have a `<pre>`; instead it has a single `<p>` tag.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it to work but I'm pretty sure I can see only a <pre> tag. Why is that?

Comment: I guess your eyes must have deceived you then.

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to parse html dom elements,

For PHP Dome parser, check the link http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

For Yahoo YQL, use this link https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

In Javascript, Jquery also there are so many methods to parse HTML.

Use which is convenient to you.

Comment: Is this the correct way?

<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = 'https://somedomain/something';
foreach ($url->getElementsByTagName("pre"){
echo $pre;
}



?>

Comment: update in ur question. in comment, i cant say anything